# How to store data from REST API into CSV every x amount of seconds

Tags: python, rest, csv

I am calling Bittrex's REST api every 3 seconds to get live ticker data. I would like to store the data as it is being called into a csv file so that I can do some analysis / back-testin on it later. I am not looking for another method for getting market data. I am simply looking for an answer to my question. Thank you!

This is what i've done so far to call the rest api every 3 seconds. How can i now store the data being received into a csv file?

```
def job():
    usdBTicker = api.getticker('USD-BTC')

    usdtBTicker = api.getticker('USDT-BTC')

    usd = api.getticker('USD-USDT')

    print("USDT:",usd['Bid'])
    print("USD-BTC:",usdBTicker['Bid'])
    print("USDT-BTC:",usdtBTicker['Bid'])

schedule.every(.033).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you even attempt to open a file and append to it?

Comment: If you want just append your .csv file use: 
`with open("data.csv", "a+") as myfile:
        myfile.write(str(usd))`